# Flutter Upgrade - The argument type 'void Function(TapDownDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragDownDetails)?'

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have upgraded the flutter but after upgrading the flutter I am getting this error:

```
The argument type 'void Function(TapDownDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragDownDetails)?'.
```

I don't understand what is causing the error. please help me.

[image]

Comment: Please explain issue clearly share example code what you are trying to do, what you are trying to achive, flutter version you are using

Comment: flutter version 3.10. Sir, I don't get where is the error coming from. I have updated my question. please see the screenshot.

Comment: You're trying to pass a function that accepts a `TapDownDetails` argument where a function that accepts a `TapDragDownDetails` is expected.  `TapDownDetails` and `TapDragDownDetails` are different classes.

Comment: I did not get this error before upgrading. but that's okay but why debug console is not showing where the error is coming from? the files it shows error is from is built in files by flutter.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76233294/latest-update-flutter-3-10-launch-error

Comment: @pskink i followed the answer mentioned in that question . but i got response in terminal that nothing to fix.

Comment: find `gesture_detector_builder.dart` and update the package this file belongs to

Comment: but how can I find that this file belongs to which package ?

Comment: @SwapnilMane The filenames in your error messages appear to be clickable links.  Other people having this problem seem to be using `package:flutter_math_fork`, which needs to be version 0.7.0 or higher to fix this problem.  If you're not consuming that package directly, run `flutter pub deps` to see what is.

Answer (score 0):

Update flutter_html to prerelease. For example, flutter_html: ^3.0.0-alpha.6